# How would I set a function that would Determined the current Date and Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

This is the Function that Determined the current Date and Time

```
var min = new Date().getMinutes(); //To get the Current Minutes
var hours = new Date().getHours(); //To get the Current Hours

var date = new Date().getDate(); //To get the Current Date
var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //To get the Current Month
var year = new Date().getFullYear(); //To get the Current Year
```

This is where the Const with the If Statement i

```
const monthInLetters = (month) => {


if (month== '3'){ return ('January')}

  
};
```

And then it gets rendered in this Text box

```
<Text style={{color: 'white' fontSize: 40}}>{date}, {month} {monthInLetters}, {year}</Text>
```

I want it to check the month of the year in numbers and then convert that to the month as a string?
How would I do that?

Comment: I tried it and it does not seem to work?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to render the function itself, rather than invoke the function and pass it a `month` value.  Did you just forget to invoke the function?  Perhaps you could be more specific about how this doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry I am new to React Native, What do you mean by passing month?

Comment: It's not specific to React Native.  It's a fundamental part of JavaScript (and almost every other popular programming language).  `monthInLetters` is a function.  It expects one parameter.  Where do you call that function and pass it that parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "check the month of the year in numbers and then convert that to the month as a string" - you can just use `toLocaleString`, e.g.

```js
const date = new Date();
const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' });
console.log(month);
```

Also there is no need to create a new date object for each part of the date. e.g.

```
var date = new Date()

var min = date.getMinutes(); //To get the Current Minutes
var hours = date.getHours(); //To get the Current Hours
var date = date.getDate(); //To get the Current Date
var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //To get the Current Month
var year = date.getFullYear(); //To get the Current Year
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for....

I also needed to change the date var to a const

Answer (score 1):

Answering as you said it doesn't work

```
const monthInLetters = (month) => {
  let months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
      return months[month - 1];
};
```

Comment: I dont know why but this returns me the whole function

Comment: you need to call the function: `{monthInLetters(month)}`